# How to find matrix $\left(\begin{matrix}a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22}\end{matrix}\right)$.

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics

I need to find all $a_{11}$ to $a_{22}$ can anyone help me pls.

$2a_{11}+3a_{21}= 3$

$2a_{12}+3a_{22}= 0$

$1a_{11}+4a_{21}= 1$

$1a_{12}+4a_{22}= 2$

I am stuck here don't know how to calculate further.

Comment: These are just simultaneous equations in the $a_{ij}$. The first and third have the same unknowns, as do the the other two.

Answer (score 1):

You have two equations sharing a two unknowns

$1a_{11}+4a_{21}=1$
therefore $a_{11} = 1 - 4a_{21}$ this lets you plug and play

\begin{align}
2a_{11}+3a_{21} & = 3 \\
2\times(1 - 4a_{21}) +3a_{21} &= 3 \\
2 - 8a_{21} +3a_{21} &= 3 \\
2 - 5a_{21} &= 3 \\
- 5a_{21} &= 1 \\
a_{21} &= -\frac{1}{5}
\end{align}

you can find the other variables via the same technique.